# Multiple Optional Parameters in SQL, how to make all results appear

Tags: sql, parameters, option-type

I'm working on a query that would allow for four optional parameters. Any of them could be filled out or none of them. My issue is, when one of the parameters is blank within my SQL, it doesn't appear in the results. For example, they could have a customer name but no company name. If they wanted to search for the customer, nothing would appear because company is null. I hope that makes sense. Any ideas? Below is a snippet of what I'm working with currently;

```
where (select cdd.TEXT_VALUE from azteca.ca_data_detail cdd
            where cdd.DETAIL_CODE = 'BFTHPREM'
            and cdd.CA_DATA_GROUP_ID = (select cdg.ca_data_group_id
                            from azteca.ca_data_group cdg
                            where cdg.GROUP_CODE = 'BFTHYDINFO'
                            and cdg.CA_OBJECT_ID = deviceTest.CA_OBJECT_ID )) is not null
    and ((assemblynumber = case @Assembly
        when '' then assemblynumber
        when null then assemblynumber
        else @Assembly
        end)
    and (peo.NAME = case @CustomerName
        when '' then peo.NAME
        when null then peo.NAME
        else @CustomerName
        end)
    and (deviceTest.LOCATION = case @Address
        when '' then deviceTest.LOCATION
        when null then deviceTest.LOCATION
        else @Address
        end)
    and (peo.COMPANY_NAME = case @CoName
        when '' then peo.COMPANY_NAME
        when null then peo.NAME
        else @CoName
        end))
```

Comment: Are you saying the company is NULL in the database, or that the user isn't entering company in the search query?

Comment: Both! It's Null in the database, so when the customer enters in the info, they'll leave that part blank, only entering in the Customer Name or address or assembly number to find it, but it doesn't return in the results when anything is blank. All fields have to have data, in the current state.

Comment: You could use something like `IFNULL(field, '')` and then match on the empty string, but that's not a great solution. What you really need is a condition that always matches (such as `1=1`) conditionally AND'd with a condition matching a value provided a user gives one